# Background columns in linechart highchart

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

I have to do a graph like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzE1L.jpg)

The linechart graph is already created, with its legend and axis label. Only the columns are missing.
I have no idea how to do it, could you help me?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: You can do that with [plot bands](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotbands-color/) - Link to the [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands)

Comment: @Core972 ok, thanks. For the interval in plotbands, How should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use plotBands on xAxis to create something similar. Mixing it with your project should return a wanted result.

```
xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
            borderColor: 'grey',
        borderWidth: 3,
        color: '#FCFFC5',
        from: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 2),
        to: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 4)
    }, { // mark the weekend
        color: '#FCFFC5',
        from: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 9),
        to: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 11)
    }, { // mark the weekend
        color: '#FCFFC5',
        from: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 16),
        to: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 18)
    }, { // mark the weekend
        color: '#FCFFC5',
        from: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 23),
        to: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 25)
    }, { // mark the weekend
        color: '#FCFFC5',
        from: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 30),
        to: Date.UTC(2019, 03, 1)
    }],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    type: 'datetime',
},
```

[Link to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nb9t4qvk/)